# python equivalent of mxCreateDoubleMatrix from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am converting MATLAB code into python code.

How can I convert `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` in MATLAB to python?

```
a = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 100, mxREAL);
```

Is there any equivalent function in python numpy or scipy for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in matlab, but it seems that function is used in C and Fortran to allocate a matlab array and return a pointer to it.
NumPy does have similar functions in its C API, see `PyArray_NewFromDescr` and the other associated functions listed at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html

My recommendation, however, would be to work with NumPy arrays through the allocation routines that are built in to NumPy.
See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html
The equivalent function there would be `zeros`

If you need to interface with C, C++, or Fortran for computation involving these arrays, I would recommend using Cython and continuing to call the built in array creation routines from there.
For some examples on how to use NumPy in Cython, see http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html